# Swapcontext - linkedlist get corrupted

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to swap context from one thread to other thread. I am maintaining a linkedlist to maintain the thread context. So the node in the linkedlist have a member of type `ucontext_t` which saves the context of a particular thread. Whenever i try to swap context, one more node is getting added at the end of linked list.

```
typedef struct nodes
{
    long int t_id;
    ucontext_t u_contxt;
    struct nodes * next;

} nodes;
```

So everytime i try to swap the context I get the current context by traversing through the linked list and pass the `ucontext` reference to the `swapcontext` as follows.

`temp1->u_contxt` points to the current context and `temp2->u_contxt` refers to the context to which i want to change

```
swapcontext(&(temp1->u_contxt),&(temp2->u_contxt));
```

Before calling the swapcontext I have only 2 nodes and one more node gets added to end of linkedlist after the return from swapcontext.

Comment: too few information to diagnose the problem. I.e. you said "thread".. is pthread or similar real concurrent multithreading involved? There is no code of how you allocate and manage the list.